# Como tendría que ser esta query?

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin, sql

Como tendría ser mi query en mi variable $rsciudad (linea 47) para que luego me muestre el dato (nombre_ciudad) correspondiente al usurio en el td y echo en la linea 82 .

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
     <?php

     $rsFerias = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM tab_certificado ORDER BY termino_curso DESC");                

       while ($ferias = mysqli_fetch_object($rsFerias)) {

             $rsmembers = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM members WHERE id = $ferias->id_alumno");
             $members = mysqli_fetch_object($rsmembers);

             $rscurso = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM tab_curso WHERE id_curso = $ferias->curso_alumno");
             $curso = mysqli_fetch_object($rscurso);

-->linea 47  $rsciudad = mysqli_query(???)

                      ?>

                      <tr>
                 <!--alumno-->
                        <td align="center">
                            <?php echo $members->rut_alumno; 
                            ?>          
                        </td>
                <!--nombre-->
                        <td>
                            <a href="ferias.php?deletar=<?php echo $ferias->id_colaborador; ?>">
                            <img src="img/ico_small_inativo.png" align="absmiddle" width="8" height="8"></a>
                            &nbsp;
                            <?php echo "<a href='cad-colaborador.php?editar=" . $members->id . "'>" . $members->username . "</a>" ?>
                        </td>
                <!--Fecha inicio Curso-->
                        <td align="center">
                            <?php echo DataBr($ferias->inicio_curso); ?>          
                        </td>
                <!--Fecha termino Curso-->
                        <td align="center">
                                      <?php echo DataBr($ferias->termino_curso); ?> 

                        <!--  <?php if (DataBr($ferias->fecha_fin) == "00/00/0000") { echo "--------"; } 
                                      else { echo DataBr($ferias->fecha_fin) . " &agrave; " . DataBr($ferias->fecha_fin); } 
                            ?>  -->           
                          </td>
    -->linea 82  <!--ciudad-->          
                        <td align="center">
                            <?php echo $ciudad->nombre_ciudad; 
                            ?>              
                          </td>
                <!--curso-->          
                          <td align="center">
                            <?php echo $curso->nombre_curso; 
                            ?>              
                          </td>
```

Comment: puedes explicar un poco mejor que deseas que te retorne toda la consulta?

Answer (score 1):

A mi parecer estas realizando una mala practica, ya que estas consumiendo tabla por tabla afectando el rendimiento de BD, lo mas recomendable es que que hagas un solo query con la información necesaria por  ejemplo

```
select 
   *
from
   tab_certificado 
inner join
   members
on
   tab_certificado .id_alumno = members.id
inner join
   tab_ciudad
on
   members.ciudad_alumno =  tab_ciudad.id_ciudad
inner join
   tab_curso
on
   members.curso_alumno =  tab_curso.id_curso
```

Con esto obtienes toda la información en un solo query, siendo mucho mas sencillo manipularlo

Saludos

Comment: vamos a probarlos gracias

Comment: lo probé y me salen todos los usuarios con el mismo nombre de  ciudad y eso que  todos tienen un id_ciudad distinto  . pero por lo menos me muestra datos . saludos

Comment: @EricBrandenberg puedes utilizar GROUP BY para poder agruparlos por algun campo en este caso GROUP BY tab_ciudad.id_ciudad

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda @Criss

Answer (score 0):

lo solucione con esta query muchas gracias a los que respondieron .

```
$rsciudad = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT ciu.nombre_ciudad from members mem
                             INNER JOIN  tab_certificado cert ON mem.id = cert.id_alumno
                             INNER JOIN tab_ciudad ciu ON mem.ciudad_alumno= ciu.id_ciudad
                             WHERE mem.id = $ferias->id_alumno");
  $ciudad = mysqli_fetch_object($rsciudad);
```